# Xcode shows unwanted log messages about anti patterns and swizzling

Tags: ios, xcode

For some reason, Xcode now prints these message when I start and debug my project.

I cannot figure out where this is coming from, why it is showing it. In the past, it didn't use to show these messages, and I am also not using any of the stuff it is showing in the log. Any ideas how to fix these message or what is triggering them?

> 2024-03-20 11:10:57.555360+0100 ProjectName[2132:934783] [
> {"framework": "Photos", "swizzle":[ {"class":"PHAsset", "methods": {
> "prefixes":["fetch","enumerate"] }, "antipattern type":"XPC on main
> thread" }, {"class":"PHFetchResult", "methods": {
> "prefixes":["fetch","enumerate"] }, "antipattern type":"XPC on main
> thread" } ] }, {"framework": "CoreLocation", "swizzle":[
> {"class":"CLLocationManager", "instance methods": {
> "names":["authorizationStatus", "monitoredRegions",
> "accuracyAuthorization"] }, "class methods": {
> "names":["locationServicesEnabled"] }, "antipattern type":"XPC on main
> thread" } ] }, {"framework":"CoreImage", "swizzle":[
> {"class":"CIContext", "instance methods": {
> "names":["createCGImage:fromRect:", "initWithOptions:"] },
> "antipattern type":"IO on main thread" } ] },
> {"framework":"HealthKit", "swizzle":[ {"class":"HKHealthStore",
> "instance methods": { "names":["authorizationStatusForType:"] },
> "antipattern type":"XPC on main thread" } ] },
> {"framework":"CoreData", "swizzle":[
> {"class":"NSManagedObjectContext", "instance methods": {
> "names":["performBlockAndWait:", "executeFetchRequest:error:",
> "mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:", "save:",
> "countForFetchRequest:error:"] }, "antipattern type":"Database access
> on main thread" } ] }, {"framework":"CoreML", "swizzle":[
> {"class":"MLModel", "class methods": {
> "names":["modelWithContentsOfURL:error:"] }, "antipattern type":"IO on
> main thread" } ] }, {"framework":"Foundation", "swizzle":[
> {"class":"NSOperation", "instance methods": {
> "names":["waitUntilFinished", "waitUntilFinishedOrTimeout:"] },
> "antipattern type":"waiting for operation completion on main thread"
> }, {"class":"NSThread", "class methods": {
> "names":["sleepForTimeInterval:"] }, "antipattern type":"Sleep" },
> {"class":"NSBundle", "instance methods": { "names":["bundlePath",
> "bundleIdentifier", "loadAndReturnError:",
> "localizedStringForKey:value:table:"] }, "class methods": {
> "names":["bundleWithIdentifier:", "allFrameworks", "allBundles",
> "pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:"] }, "antipattern type":"IO on
> main thread" }, {"class":"NSKeyedArchiver", "class methods": {
> "names":["archivedDataWithRootObject:",
> "archivedDataWithRootObject:requiringSecureCoding:error:",
> "archiveRootObject:toFile:"] }, "antipattern type":"IO on main thread"
> }, {"class":"NSKeyedUnarchiver", "class methods": {
> "names":["unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData:error:",
> "decodeObjectForKey:", "unarchiveObjectWithData:"] }, "antipattern
> type":"IO on main thread" }, {"class":"NSFileManager", "methods": {
> "prefixes":["remove", "create", "move", "copy"] }, "instance methods":
> {
> "names":["synchronouslyGetFileProviderServicesForItemAtURL:completionHandler:"]
> }, "antipattern type":"IO on main thread" }, {"class":"NSData",
> "methods": { "prefixes":["initWithContents", "dataWithContents"] },
> "instance methods": { "names":["enumerateByteRangesUsingBlock:"] },
> "antipattern type":"IO on main thread" } ] }, {"framework":"AVFCore",
> "swizzle":[ {"class":"AVAsset", "class methods": {
> "names":["assetWithURL:"] }, "antipattern type":"IO on main thread" },
> {"class":"AVAsset", "instance methods": {
> "names":["mediaSelectionGroupForMediaCharacteristic:"] }, "antipattern
> type":"Conditional waiting on main thread" }, {"class":"AVAsset",
> "instance methods": { "names":["tracksWithMediaType:"] }, "antipattern
> type":"XPC on main thread" }, {"class":"AVURLAsset", "instance
> methods": { "names":["tracks"] }, "antipattern type":"XPC on main
> thread" } ] }, {"framework":"AVFAudio", "swizzle":[
> {"class":"AVAudioSession", "instance methods": {
> "names":["setActive:withOptions:error:", "category",
> "setCategory:mode:options:error:",
> "setCategory:mode:routeSharingPolicy:options:error:",
> "setCategory:withOptions:error:", "setCategory:error:",
> "currentRoute", "outputVolume",
> "setAllowHapticsAndSystemSoundsDuringRecording:error:",
> "isPiPAvailable"] }, "antipattern type":"XPC on main thread" } ] },
> {"framework":"StoreKit", "swizzle":[ {"class":"SKPaymentQueue", "class
> methods": { "names":["canMakePayments"] }, "antipattern
> type":"Semaphore on main thread" }, {"class":"SKPaymentQueue",
> "instance methods": { "names":["storefront"] }, "antipattern
> type":"XPC on main thread" } ] }, {"framework":"CoreTelephony",
> "swizzle":[ {"class":"CTCellularPlanProvisioning", "instance methods":
> { "names":["supportsCellularPlan"] }, "antipattern type":"Semaphore on
> main thread" } ] }, {"framework":"Vision", "swizzle":[
> {"class":"VNImageRequestHandler", "methods": {
> "prefixes":["performRequest"] }, "antipattern type":"Computer vision
> tasks on main thread" } ] } ]

I have created a breakpoint on NSLog, and this is it's backtrace:

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.2
  * frame #0: 0x00000001a2de441c Foundation`NSLog
    frame #1: 0x00000001057f0998 libRPAC.dylib`swizzleAPIsForHangDetection + 104
    frame #2: 0x00000001057f22a0 libRPAC.dylib`initializeTrampolineBasedSwizzling + 84
    frame #3: 0x000000010576e578 libRPAC.dylib`__library_initializer + 1756
    frame #4: 0x00000001c7422a84 dyld`invocation function for block in dyld4::Loader::findAndRunAllInitializers(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const::$_0::operator()() const + 168
    frame #5: 0x00000001c7412208 dyld`invocation function for block in dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::forEachInitializer(Diagnostics&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::VMAddrConverter const&, void (unsigned int) block_pointer, void const*) const + 340
    frame #6: 0x00000001c74103c8 dyld`invocation function for block in dyld3::MachOFile::forEachSection(void (dyld3::MachOFile::SectionInfo const&, bool, bool&) block_pointer) const + 496
    frame #7: 0x00000001c741015c dyld`dyld3::MachOFile::forEachLoadCommand(Diagnostics&, void (load_command const*, bool&) block_pointer) const + 300
    frame #8: 0x00000001c741a67c dyld`dyld3::MachOFile::forEachSection(void (dyld3::MachOFile::SectionInfo const&, bool, bool&) block_pointer) const + 192
    frame #9: 0x00000001c7419228 dyld`dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::forEachInitializer(Diagnostics&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::VMAddrConverter const&, void (unsigned int) block_pointer, void const*) const + 516
    frame #10: 0x00000001c7418dac dyld`dyld4::Loader::findAndRunAllInitializers(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const + 524
    frame #11: 0x00000001c743bd84 dyld`dyld4::JustInTimeLoader::runInitializers(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const + 36
    frame #12: 0x00000001c74188d8 dyld`dyld4::Loader::runInitializersBottomUp(dyld4::RuntimeState&, dyld3::Array<dyld4::Loader const*>&) const + 220
    frame #13: 0x00000001c741873c dyld`dyld4::Loader::runInitializersBottomUpPlusUpwardLinks(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const::$_1::operator()() const + 116
    frame #14: 0x00000001c74184cc dyld`dyld4::Loader::runInitializersBottomUpPlusUpwardLinks(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const + 380
    frame #15: 0x00000001c7411120 dyld`dyld4::APIs::runAllInitializersForMain() + 336
    frame #16: 0x00000001c740fb98 dyld`dyld4::prepare(dyld4::APIs&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer const*) + 3328
    frame #17: 0x00000001c740eb80 dyld`start + 1724
```

Comment: Same issue, plus my app hangs on launch before didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is called. The console logs a bunch of errors containing "antipattern trigger"

Comment: Same problem in an empty project started from the Multiplatform > App template (with SwiftData and Host in CloudKit checked). But @Rand: for the hang, if you get a message about logging right after the hang is done, I found a workaround on the Apple dev forums. Add these two arguments to your Scheme > Run > Environment Variables: IDELogRedirectionPolicy=oslogToStdio and OS_ACTIVITY_MODE=OS_ACTIVITY_MODE .
I don't have deeper knowledge of what this does, but simply set a reminder to check and remove if/when this bug is fixed in Xcode.

Comment: Thank you @AlexFringes I "solved" my problem by eventually wiping all traces of Xcode from my system and then adding my work in progress a bit at a time back into my branch, only to find it no longer hanging… I'll save this for next time though.